# php 5.3 convert array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I have the following code, and I'd like to get away from the call-time pass-by-reference, (To convert from 5.2 to 5.3) but I'm not sure exactly sure what the correct way to do this would be (class, global variable, ?)

Here is a codepad that should have everything in it
http://codepad.org/ombgFPMR

```
<?php

function count_things($item, $key, $total) {
    $total++;
}

$counts = array(100 => 1,
            101 => 1,
            102 => array(
                106 => 1,
                107 => 1
            ),
            103 => 1,
            104 => 1,
            105 => array(
                108 => 1,
                109 => array(
                    110 => 1,
                    111 => 1,
                    112 => 1
                )
            )
        );

foreach($counts as $key => $count) {
    $total = 0;

    if(is_array($count)) {
            $total++;
            /* The below is a logic error. Array elements that contain arrays do not get
               the callback function called on them. Therefore, any children with children
               of their own will not be counted. In the output of this paste,
               the final key, $final_counts[105]['total'], should have a value of 6, but it
               actually has a value of 5. */
    array_walk_recursive($count, 'count_things', &$total);
} else {
            $total = $count;
    }

    $final_counts[$key]['total'] = $total;
}   

print_r($final_counts);

?>
```

Output looks like:

```
Array
(
[100] => Array
    (
        [total] => 1
    )

[101] => Array
    (
        [total] => 1
    )

[102] => Array
    (
        [total] => 3
    )

[103] => Array
    (
        [total] => 1
    )

[104] => Array
    (
        [total] => 1
    )

[105] => Array
    (
        [total] => 5
    )

)
```

Comment: Your codepad is using PHP 5.2. Here is one with 5.3: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NULi0P

Comment: @bfavaretto: Thanks, but that doesn't really help.  He wants to remove the "Call-time pass-by-reference".

Comment: @Rocket I know, I added the new link so we can actually see the problem live.

Comment: I wonder if `array_reduce` could be useful here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You can use `count` with `COUNT_RECURSIVE` flag.</del>

You should use closures for this, these were introduced in 5.3.0 so they should work.

```
<?php

$counts = array(
    100 => 1,
    101 => 1,
    102 => array(
        106 => 1,
        107 => 1
    ),
    103 => 1,
    104 => 1,
    105 => array(
        108 => 1,
        109 => array(
            110 => 1,
            111 => 1,
            112 => 1
        )
    )
);

$final_counts = array();

foreach($counts as $key => $count) {

    if(is_array($count)) {
        $total = 1;
        array_walk_recursive($count, function() use (&$total) {
            $total++;
        });
    } else {
        $total = $count;
    }

    $final_counts[$key]['total'] = $total;
}

print_r($final_counts);
```

I might be able to provide a better solution if you put your problem in context.

Comment: Nice idea, but it's producing a different count for key `105` (`6` instead of `5`).

Comment: @bfavaretto: Pretty sure it's supposed to actually be `6` (meaning the OP's code isn't right).  If `102` is `3`, then `105` should be `6`.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That doesn't make the OP's algorithm correct :-P

Comment: Yeah sorry this is wrong. Count with recursive flag counts all arrays plus its elements, not just the elements. I've updated my post to use closures.

Comment: @ddlshack: +1 Nice job w/ the closures!

Comment: This is the OP's coworker. When he originally posted it, he helpfully deleted my code comment (which he has now penitently added back) that explained that there was indeed a logic error and the output was wrong. The count for `105` should indeed have been 6, and `count` with `COUNT_RECURSIVE` does just fine. I apologize for the trouble; I wrote the original code, but IANAP and this code should never have seen the light of day outside our office.